# Why am I allowed to write and use methods in an implementation that aren't declared in the header file in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
}
@end

@implementation SomeClass
-(void) awesomeMethod600
{
}
@end
```

No error, and awesomeMethod600 works.

Answer (score 7):

The method declarations in the class interfaces are there for the compiler (to suppress warnings), since method lookup in Objective-C is done at runtime, and *not* compile time.

Comment: For the compiler to do what with? There must be some difference when I omit them. Is it so it can throw warnings if I supply arguments against the definition? Can it generate faster code?

Oh, you edited it.

Comment: The compiler will check whether the methods you call are declared in any class interfaces that it knows about. If it can't find them it will emit a warning, but this is not necessarily an error as the actual lookup for that method call is done at runtime by the Objective-C runtime, and the method may not actually be in place at compile time (you can do stuff with the Objective-C runtime methods such as dynamically adding methods to classes at runtime, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Perspx is right.

Try building this in XCode:

```
@implementation SomeClass
-(void)awesomeMethod {
    [self notAwesomeMethod];
}    

-(void)notAwesomeMethod {}
@end
```

You should see a warning that says *'SomeClass' may not respond to '-notAwesomeMethod'*. Try inverting the order of the method definitions... no error since `notAwesomeMethod` is now already defined, and thus the compiler knows about it. Class interfaces do this upfront.

This is also nice behavior because you can choose to only publicize the class's **public** interface, and keep any internal private methods out of the `.h` file.

Comment: It's also kind of NOT nice behavior because then if someone learns about your private methods, they ARE in fact available, you just get warnings...